# How can I make an array in my extension using information from a webpage?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

this is all in Javascript

I have been trying to make an array in my extension with all the results from one page of a google search but it's not working,

```
let listOfResults = [];


resultsCount = () => {
chrome.tabs.forEach(cite =>  { 
    listOfResults.push(cite)
    });

};
```

I'm this seems right but I'm not sure what the correct syntax and functions to use.